# What are the eval()-related functions to be avoided when CSP is enabled?

Tags: javascript, eval, content-security-policy

I bundle my React app with Webpack and add [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) headers (in particular, not allowing `unsafe-eval` in `script-src`). Of course, I make sure my final bundle and chunks do not contain `eval()`. However, latest Firefox-dev 63.0b10 still refuses to load the main chunk with the following error:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at self (“script-src”). Source: call to eval() or related
>   function blocked by CSP.

Well, but I don't have `eval()` in my bundle.
What those "related functions" could be?

<sub>P.S. This is a [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but feel free to extend</sub>

Answer (score 6):

[Mozilla docs on CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#Sources), lists "`eval()` and similar methods" as possible offenders:

> […] `'unsafe-eval'`
>       Allows the use of `eval()` and similar methods for creating code from strings. […]

[CSP3 specification § 1.2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#goals), mentions "`eval()` and similar constructs":

> Mitigate the risk of content-injection attacks by giving developers
>   fairly granular control over […] Dynamic code execution (via `eval()` and similar constructs) […]

But the final answer is further in  CSP3 spec, in [§ 6.1.10.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#directive-script-src):

> The following JavaScript execution sinks are gated on the
>   "`unsafe-eval`" source expression:
>
> - `eval()`
> - `Function()`
> - `setTimeout()` with an initial argument which is not callable.
> - `setInterval()` with an initial argument which is not callable.
>
> Note: If a user agent implements non-standard sinks like
>   `setImmediate()` or `execScript()`, they SHOULD also be gated on
>   "`unsafe-eval`".

So, for CSP purposes, the complete list of "dynamic code execution constructs",  `eval()`'s "similar methods", "related functions", "similar constructs" is:

```
eval()
Function()     // typically new Function()
setTimeout()   // with non-callable argument
setInterval()  // with non-callable argument
setImmediate()
execScript()
```

In my case, I found a few `new Function(...)` fragments in the bundle and now figuring out how to prevent them from appearing.

#### Bonus

If you take [`grepl`](https://gist.github.com/xuhdev/234728cdb46cdd88ce02742fe5ecf6cd) or a similar `grep`-like tool that finds string matches and prints surrounding context in char-by-char basis (rather than line-by-line, as normal `grep`) you can use the following command to find "dynamic code execution constructs" in all of the files of your bundled (minified and code-split) app:

```
find "<build_dir>" -type f -iname "*.js" -exec grepl -k 512 -H "(eval|Function)(\s|\t)*\(" '{}' \;
```

Alternatively, you could turn off JS minifier (e.g. UglifyJS) and inspect your build with normal `grep`.

Comment: If someone else is asking himself how to call `setTimeout()` with an initial argument which **is** callable even if you are already calling a function: Just wrap the thing you are calling with `setTimeout()` into an anonymous function. E. g. change `setTimeout(console.log('not working'), 1000);` to `setTimeout(function(){console.log('working');}, 1000);`.